# How show comments approved by custom form Orchard CMS

Tags: forms, content-management-system, orchardcms

Here my question : How can I show, on a page, all the comments I received from a custom form throught Orchard CMS ?

If your not sure to understand my question, here an example of what I want :

Create a Guestbook with a new Content Type named "Gestbook". Add two fields (the name and the comment). Once add it on Forms tab, add comments into the new guestbook page into your website. After that, how can I show them after approved it throught dashboard ?

Thank you very much,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on "submissions" on the right of the form in the Forms section of the admin to see what got added by users. You can also trigger additional actions from the Rules module.

Comment: Yeah, I see the comment added by users and I approved all of these. But I cannot show them in a public page. By example, my guestbook is from http://localhost:45620/Guestbook and each comment have it's own url adress : http://localhost:45620/Contents/Item/Display/60. I want to show all of them in one unique page like http://localhost:45620/Guestbook. How can I do that please ? Thank you !

Comment: Oh I find the way to do !! I made a projection with Guestbook comments filter and associate a new page with it, that it's !!